# How to start a single timer and access it from multiple views?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nstimer

What is the recommended approach for starting a countdown `NSTimer` on one view and having it be accessible to stop interactively or to have run out in another?

I know one option is to have the `NSTimer` never turn off once kicked off and just use a global variable to determine whether to countdown or not but that seems inefficient.

More details of what I'm trying do:

In the main view I have a label that will update with the count down 00:00:00 and a button that I want to open a countdown `UIDatePicker`.

The second view with the `UIDatePicker` also has a start and stop button that will kick off or stop the countdown.

This view will close and the label on the original screen will display the countdown based on what the user selected previously.

Comment: I would keep track of time not the timer object, then destroy and re-create the timer with the updated time whenever needed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the timer you needed is independent from any of the views. You can use a singleton instance which will init once then be accessed anywhere. It's kind of like a global variable you mention above but if you have more than two views that need access to the timer singleton might be the most suitable choose

Comment: I'll try the destroy and recreate option above and then test the singleton approach for practice. thanks